# Using model method name for id in a custom helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have the following helper I built so I can have a date picker field:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DatePickerFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> property, string minDate = "2012-01-01", string maxDate = "2100-01-01")
    {
        TModel model = helper.ViewData.Model;
        var builder = new TagBuilder("input");
        builder.Attributes.Add("id", "id");
        builder.Attributes.Add("type", "date");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());

    }
```

What I want to do is to generate the ID and the name from the model method I pass to it from my view exactly like you can do with any other EditorFor or RadioButtonFor fields.

In the view I call it this way:

```
@Html.DatePickerFor(model => model.EntryDate)
```

So in that case I'd like the ID and name to be "EntryDate". I tried looking in `helper.ViewData` and other metadata and couldn't find anything near to what I could work with. The term "model method name" might be wrong so please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Are you using strongly typed view? If you mark yours Model properte with the attribute DataType = DataType.Date the html generate by the EditorFor will be an input type = Date

Comment: Yes I am but there's more to it that I don't show here that explains why I'm creating a custom helper instead of the EditorFor with DataType.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to employ use Expressions code like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression) to get the property name as a string.

Here's the key bit, where action is your lambda `model => model.EntryDate`:

```
var expression = (MemberExpression)action.Body;
string name = expression.Member.Name;
```